# `pk` and `id` are not identical when coping instances with inheritance

Tags: django

I am aware that `pk` is preferable because `id` is builtins.They are identical.

However, reference to copy instances which use inheritance, it's not complicated to distinguish them:

In the official tutorial [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances)

```
#Due to how inheritance works, you have to set both pk and id to None:
django_blog.pk = None
django_blog.id = None
django_blog.save() # django_blog.pk == 4
```

There, `pk` is definitely not identical to `id`

How to understand it?

Comment: what is ‘id’ after you save the model?

Comment: You enlightened me @munk could you please transmit the short comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action of [saving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) gives your model an id. This will populate your `id` and `pk` attributes.

The documentation probably could be more complete by stressing that both would be set.

Comment: Does it matter, if I reverse the their order as: `django_blog.id = None, django_blog.pk = None`

Comment: I wouldn't imagine so - but I would suggest simply trying it yourself.